# SwiftUI - List Divider: Unwanted inset at the start when non-Text component is used at the start of row

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-list

**Description**

When an `HStack`'ed list row components start with a non-`Text` and is followed by a `Text` component, then line `Divider` start from the first `Text` occurrence in the row. What I expect is `Divider` to stretch through the row. I have tried all the combination of `listSyle()` on the `List` but none resolved the problem. As seen in the pic, the divider ignores anything placed before the `Text`.

[image]

**Question**

Is there any way to force the `Divider` stretch through the row?

**Steps to reproduce**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            HStack{
                Image(systemName: "star")
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                Text("Chocolate")
            }
            HStack{
                Image(systemName: "star")
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                Text("Waffles")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Environment**

- Xcode version info: `Xcode 14.0.1`
- Deployment target: `iOS 14.0`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove/adjust separators in List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56498871/how-to-remove-adjust-separators-in-list)

Comment: @lazarevzubov Most of the comments point out that answers are buggy

Comment: I didn't like the answers that were here so far as they ether didn't fix the Separator's leading spacing or just seemed to add another one over the top so I used a hidden textbox at the start. See: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76698909/769294)

Answer (score 3):

You can convert the system images to text, then the line will start there:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            HStack{
                Text(Image(systemName: "star")) // here
                Text("Chocolate")
            }
            HStack{
                Text(Image(systemName: "star")) // here
                Text("Waffles")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `Image` has more complex content than it is shown in the code. That is why I specifically mentioned non-`Text` component not just `Image`. It was just a smaple code to reproduce. Imagine it is another `VStack` instead of `Image`

Answer (score 2):

## Cause

Although I have yet to find any official Apple documentation on this it appears to be by design so the line always starts at the text (see the Settings app).

## My reason for wanting this

But I wanted a full width button with centred text and didn't want the seperator starting half way across the list row.

## Solution

The way I went about solving this was to just put the text it wanted at the start so iOS knew what I wanted.

I did this by adding an empty 0 width text box before the actual row content and wrapping the whole thing in another HStack with 0 spacing (otherwise it indents it slightly).

While this is still very Hacky it does remove the bugs the other answers up to now have.

## Example

[image]

```
// Extra HStack with "hidden" text entry at the start.
HStack(spacing: 0) {
    Text("").frame(maxWidth: 0)
    
    // Original row data here...
    Button {
        // Do something here
    } label: {
        Text("Full Width Button")
            // Make this text entry take up all the row
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    }
    .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
}
// Just to help the separator stand out
.listRowSeparatorTint(.red)

// Second Row so the separator shows up
Button("Another") {}.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
```

## Potential side effect

I've tested it with `Accessibility - Spoken Content` enabled and I can't hear any issues with the extra text box.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to hide the separator and manually add a `Divider()` in between the rows. The divider will appear centered in the list.

```
var body: some View {
    List {
        HStack{
            Image(systemName: "star")
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            Text("Chocolate")
        }
        .listRowSeparator(.hidden)      // Hide the separator

        // Add a manual divider
        Divider()
        
        HStack{
            Image(systemName: "star")
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            Text("Waffles")
        }
        .listRowSeparator(.hidden)      // Hide the separator
    }
}
```

Comment: That API is supported only in iOS 15+

Comment: and you say your deployment target is iOS 16

Comment: @ChrisR I edited the question. it was mistake, thanks for noticing

Answer (score 1):

Weird behaviour, understandable if using "system images". Work around as described above!

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct CenterText: View {
let text: String

init(_ text: String) {
    self.text = text
}

var body: some View {
    HStack {
        Text("").frame(maxWidth: 0)
        Spacer()
        Text(text)
        Spacer()
    }
 }
}

struct CenterText_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
    List {
        Text("Top")
        CenterText("CenterTextListItem")
        Text("Bottom")
        // wrong behaviour
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            Text("No full divider line")
            Spacer()
        }
        Text("Final Bottom")
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a possible.
The `listRowSeparator` has parameter `edges`.
If you call that with .all, the separators stretch through the row.
And then, there are three choise `hidden`, `automatic` and `visible`.
`visible` effects force a edge options.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            HStack{
                Image(systemName: "star")
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                Text("Chocolate")
            }.listRowSeparator(.visible, edges: .all)
            
            HStack{
                Image(systemName: "star")
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                Text("Waffles")
            }.listRowSeparator(.visible, edges: .all)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It has a restricted usage. Supported only after iOS 15+

Comment: Yes, You are using iOS 16. right?

Comment: It was mistake, I edited it. It is 14

Comment: I have no idea. You need to build List like view using ScrollView.

Comment: the .visible forces the divider to go full from edge to edge. the default behavior would be a space between the edge and the divider line, trailing and leading.